# Rigid Body simulation glitching/jittering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rigid-body-simulation

I'm getting strange jumpy/jittery playback on my rigid body fall simulation when previewing in 'Rendered view'. This also occurs when exporting as an image sequence too. It works fine in 'Material Preview' and 'Solid' view.

What I can't understand is that this wasn't happening a few weeks ago when I rendered out the first draft, I've only noticed it not working properly when I've come to make some amendments today.

[Screen recording here](https://imgur.com/a/mwF6WMm)

Thanks in advance,

Ben.

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE. Did you bake your animation? Then after baking, try *Object > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes*

Comment: It wasn't happening when you rendered out the first draft... you mean you rendered an image sequence or video clip and that wasn't jittering on playback? Well, of course not because Blender finished rendering. What I see in your screen recording is the rendered preview which is rendered real-time while playing back the animation and each frame has to be rendered on the fly in the moment it is played. Of course this can be jittery because it uses a lot of resources from your computer, and that's especially slow when your GPU and/or CPU might not be the fastest (I don't know your specs).

Comment: And if together with this the simulation is not baked as @HarryMcKenzie suspected (although I guess it's at least in the cache if _Solid_ and _Material Preview_ are running smoother), your computer is in "double trouble", having to simulate on the fly and rendering at the same time. And if you then even make a screen recording on top of that... as I said, I  do not know your hardware specifications, but your machine is probably just not fast enough to show a rendered preview of the animation...?